# SQL, W3school practice problem - find the product that was ordered most with by customers in France

Tags: sql, sqlite

doing a practice problem on W3school - the database is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/TRYSQL.ASP?FILENAME=TRYSQL_SELECT_ALL): https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/TRYSQL.ASP?FILENAME=TRYSQL_SELECT_ALL

I'm trying to return the Product (found in table `OrderDetails`) that was ordered the most by customers in the Country France (`Country` is found in the table `Customers`). To do this I first had to join across 3 tables: first by joining `OrderDetails` and `Orders` on `OrderID`, and then joining the merged table with `Customers` on `CustomerID`. Problem is, now that I have the table, I can't seem to figure out how to return the ProductID that was ordered the most by customers in France.. The following code:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    SUM(od.Quantity) AS totalQuantity
    FROM (OrderDetails od LEFT JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
    LEFT JOIN Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    GROUP BY od.ProductID
    ORDER BY totalQuantity DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

returns the error:

```
Syntax error in ORDER BY clause
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here? Is what I'm doing even getting close to returning the ProductID that was ordered the most by customers in France?

Comment: Just a guess, since you have not specified which database you use, but you should remove the () in the from line.

Comment: Oh sorry does the link not work? I think I need the parentheses in the from line because you need to use parentheses if you do multiple joins?

Comment: Also, I believe this is MS Access, which is why I needed to place the parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` isn't Access SQL syntax, so try:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    od.ProductID,
    SUM(od.Quantity) AS totalQuantity
FROM 
    (OrderDetails AS od 
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders AS o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
LEFT JOIN 
    Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    od.ProductID
ORDER BY 
    SUM(od.Quantity) DESC;
```

Comment: That does it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools is using WebSQL that connects to a SqLite 3

You can check it's version :

```
SELECT sqlite_version();
```

The query in the question doesn't work because it selects `c.customer_id`, which should be `c.CustomerID`.

This query will return the product with the most unique customers in France.

The country is taken from the Customers table.
The Products table is only joined to get the name of the product.

```
SELECT 
  od.ProductID
, p.ProductName
, COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
, COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustomerID) AS TotalCustomers
, SUM(od.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM "OrderDetails" AS od
INNER JOIN "Orders" AS o ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN "Customers" AS c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN "Products" AS p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
WHERE c.Country = 'France' 
GROUP BY od.ProductID, p.ProductName
ORDER BY TotalCustomers DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It's a meat pie.

Comment: What a bonehead mistake, sometimes when you grapple with something for so long you start to get sloppy. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT
c.CustomerID, c.Country,
SUM(od.Quantity) AS totalQuantity
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON (c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails od ON (od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
where c.Country = 'France'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.Country
ORDER BY totalQuantity DESC;
```

this will give an output the quantity of order of customers in France